# Delete all "No Fill" rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

This works to delete Yellow (index 6), but `0` does not clear the "NO Fill" rows, any ideas?

```
Sub deleterow()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim delRange As Range

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 7 To 1200 '<~~ Row 7 to 1200
        For j = 1 To 180 '<~~ Col A to end of last dealer
            If .Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then '0=No Fill
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Cells(i, j)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Cells(i, j))
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about trying

```
.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
```

Comment: -4142 is the value for xlColorIndexNone, one of the values of xlColorIndex enum.

Comment: If you are not sure of the number you can always Msgbox the range's interior.colorindex